# file reader does not display the content of text file

Tags: javascript

I saved this javascript code as html and then tried to open it using mozilla firefox :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function onChange(event) {
var file = event.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {

console.log(event.target.result)
};

reader.readAsText(file);
}
</script>

<input type="file" onchange="onChange(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox asked to choose a file , which I did but to my surprise it did not display the content of the text file I chose but only its name . What am I missing ?

Comment: This script works fine for me. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: works fine on my side

Comment: I am expecting it to display me the paragraph inside the text file I , locally ,  chose , from my laptop through the option " browse" that I got in Mozilla page . However it did not show anything . The page is white .